# Filter database table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like below

```
  |-----|-----|--------|
  | id  | num | amount |
  |-----|-----|--------|
  | 101 | a   |     10 |      
  | 102 | a   |      6 |   
  | 102 | a   |      3 |
  | 101 | b   |      5 |
  | 101 | a   |     10 |
  | 101 | b   |      5 |           
  |-----|-----|--------|
```

What i want to display is

```
  |---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |        id           |     num          |        amount       |
  |---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |       101           |       a,b        |          5          |        
  |---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

I.e if two different values in num table have the same id then their amount is added and divided by 3 and others are discarded. How can i achieve this using mysql?? If also same data is repeated twice only one and first occurance is taken and another one is eliminated

I have tried

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT num) AS nums, SUM(amount) / 3 AS amount
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT num) > 1
```

But it calculate both values i.e amount is 10 instead of 5.

Comment: How should you pick which duplicated values to add? For your sample data, you have a=10 & a=3 for id=101. Which a value should be used for the calculation?

Comment: Only one that first occured.

Comment: What do you mean by "first occured"? By which criteria?

Comment: There are multiple duplicate values. I just want one that satisfies the condition

Comment: This question has gone through a lot of changes from the original version. Is this the final version do you think?

Comment: Yess final question

Comment: sql data is stored in unordered sets - there is no such thing as 'first 'occurred' ,unless you have column which can identify the order in which events occurred (such as an auto_increment id column or a timestamp) no query can be guaranteed to return the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complicated problem as there is no natural ordering in the table. So we have to create an artificial ordering by generating row numbers for each entry in the table. We do that with this query:

```
SELECT @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 AS rownum, id, num, amount
FROM table1
JOIN (SELECT @rownum1 := 0) r
```

This gives the following output:

```
rownum  id      num     amount
1       101     a       10
2       102     a       6
3       102     a       3
4       101     b       5
5       101     a       3
6       101     b       5
```

Once we've done that, we can now select a set of values for each combination of `id` and `num` that represent the "first" entries in the table:

```
SELECT id, num, MIN(rownum) AS rownum
FROM (SELECT @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rownum, id, num, amount
      FROM table1
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
      ) t
GROUP BY id, num;
```

Output:

```
id      num     rownum
101     a       1
101     b       4
102     a       2
```

Now that we have that information, we can `JOIN` the sorted table to this information and then use the original query on that result set to get the results for the "first" occurrences of each set of values:

```
SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.num) AS nums, SUM(t1.amount) / 3 AS amount
FROM (SELECT @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 AS rownum, id, num, amount
      FROM table1
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum1 := 0) r
      ) t1
JOIN (SELECT id, num, MIN(rownum) AS rownum
      FROM (SELECT @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rownum, id, num, amount
            FROM table1
            JOIN (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
            ) t
      GROUP BY id, num) t2
    ON t1.rownum = t2.rownum
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.num) > 1;
```

Output:

```
id      nums    amount
101     a,b     5
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d8ee07/21)

Comment: You are Mindblowing dude. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a subquery for distinct   and join with the id with count > 1

```
  select  t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT( t1.num) AS nums, SUM(t1.amount) / 3 AS amount
  from (
     select distinct  id, num, amount
     from table1  
     group by id, num
  ) t1
  INNER JOIN (
    select id, num, count(*)
    from table1
    group by id, num 
    having count(*)>1 

  ) t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Comment: anyway answer updated ..missing  1 in having count(*) >